# Настроить роут с изменчивой ссылкой

Tags: vue.js, rest

Как можно описать маппинг роута на ссылку, в которой последний параметр может меняться.

```
{ path: '/user/{id}', //изменчивый параметр id
  name: 'Profile',
  component: Profile }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать во [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/) динамический сегмент в маршруте, чтобы настроить динамический путь, например:

```
{ path: '/user/:id', component: Profile, name: 'user-id' }
```

Динамический сегмент обозначается **двоеточием [ : ]**.

Теперь все URL вида `/user/foo` и `/user/bar` будут соответствовать одному маршруту.

При сопоставлении маршрута таким образом, значение динамического сегмента (`id`) можно получить через `this.$route.params` в каждом сопоставленном компоненте.

Более подробно об этом: [Динамические пути во vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)

Практический пример:

```js
const Profile = {
  template: '<div><h1>Профиль</h1> {{ $route.params.id }} <h3>Полный путь</h3> {{$route.path}}</div>'
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: '/user/:id',
    component: Profile,
    name: 'user-id'
  }]
})


new Vue({
  router,
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.8.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user in ['victor', 'ivan', 'sergey']" :key='user'>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'user-id', params: { id: user } }"> {{user}} </router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```